# Converting Excel rows to columns (smarter than transpose)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that has been output by an accounting system, but needs massaging. 
Each Invoice is output on a row, but the categories of the products on the invoice are output as a column - I want all the data to be on a row.

[image: Excel Sample Image]

(I've just discovered that as a new user to here I can't post an image, so this link links to a jpg that explains what I mean)

So the image shows how the data is currently output and how it needs to be. I assume that I need to use VBA to do this (there's actually 1000's of rows of data and a new sheet is generated every day), but I'm interested in any other ideas or samples of what functions to use in VBA (I'm a delphi developer and haven't written anything in VBA for many years, but I'm sure I can turn my hand to it with a few hints!)

Many Thanks

David

Comment: How many _distinct_ types in Column G? Will there be a certain range, or it's totally dynamic?

Comment: If you follow the "fillempty" steps outlined here -  http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/fillempt.htm you can then use a pivot table for this.

Comment: @Passerby at the moment it's about 15. It's a config setting in the software that exports, so it could go up but if a VBA routine was involved, that could be changed at the same time.

Comment: @DavidRose VBA sucks at working with arrays, and `Dictionary` is kind of slow, so if the product type is dynamic and you have many data, I would suggest you to try what Tim said: fill the blank and use pivot table. It's still possible in VBA though. Do you really want an VBA solution anyway?

Comment: @Passerby - I've come up with a completely "out of the box" idea to fix the problem, might work, might not - will know in a day or two :)